# Zone configuration not working

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, centos, ipv4, dns-zone

I have these 3 files to configure a zone :

/etc/named.conf

```
zone "exemple.tn" IN {
type master;
file "/var/named/db.exemple.tn";
allow-update {none;};
};

zone "85.168.192.in-addr.arpa" {
type master ;
file "/var/named/db.cba.tn" ;
allow-update {none;};
} ;
```

/etc/var/db.exemple.tn

```
$ORIGIN exemple.tn.
$TTL 84600
@ IN SOA ns.exemple.tn. root@exemple.tn. (
123312 ; serial
1h ;refresh
2h ;retry
1w ;expire
1h) ;min cache
@ IN NS ns.exemple.tn.
@ IN A 192.168.25.128
ns IN A 192.168.85.129
```

/var/named/db.cba.tn

```
$TTL 86400
@ IN SOA ns.exemple.tn. root.ns.exemple.tn. (
4
10800
3600
604800
86400 )
@ IN NS ns.exmple.tn.
129 IN PTR ns.exemple.tn.
```

and when i run the command :

```
# named-checkzone exemple.tn /var/named/db.cba.tn
```

i get this error : 
zone exemple.tn/IN: NS 'ns.exmple.tn' has no adress records (A or AAAA)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please obfuscate more carefully: is the zone exemple.tn, , exmple.tn or esprit.tn.

Comment: Sorry,  edited the zone is exemple.tn

Comment: And I ran the command with "checkzone 85.168.192.in-addr.arpa /var/named/db.cba.tn" and it worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are plenty of obvious problems.

1. Your command `named-checkzone exemple.tn /var/named/db.cba.tn` validates the contents of a zone with name `exemple.tn` reading its data from the file `/var/named/db.cba.tn`.
   However, looking at your provided configuration and zone data, `/var/named/db.cba.tn` seems to have data for the reverse zone `85.168.192.in-addr.arpa` (for `192.168.85.0/24`), not the zone `exemple.tn`.
   To make this less confusing, you may want to consider naming that file `db.85.168.192.in-addr.arpa` or something along those lines to make it more obvious what it actually is.
2. The `NS` record in this reverse zone points to `ns.exmple.tn.` which is similar enough to `ns.exemple.tn.` in one of your other zones that I have to wonder if that is a typo or intentional?
3. The `SOA` `RNAME` in your `exemple.tn` zone is `root@exemple.tn` but that should probably be `root.exemple.tn` (if you actually accept mail sent to `root@exemple.tn` at all, otherwise probably something else entirely).
   Similarly, I have to wonder if the `SOA` `RNAME` in the reverse zone should simply have the same value?
4. The actual error message is from a check based on an actual lookup of that name. Depending on the circumstances you may want to only validate local data (see the `-i` option)

Comment: thanks for taking time to respond.  So,  the address of the server is 192.168.85.129 and that's what I did put in the reverse zone file "129 IN.." did I do something we wrong there?

Comment: @MoatezBouhdid The `PTR` record looks ok to me. Do see the other problems I pointed out, however.

Comment: can you clarify on the 2nd point pls cause i didn't undrestand it.

Comment: @MoatezBouhdid `ns.exmple.tn.` != `ns.exemple.tn.`. Is the use of `ns.exmple.tn.` in that single place intentional or a typo?